# integrate EasyPost with cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, easypost

Trying to integrate this:
https://github.com/EasyPost/easypost-php

When I run this code blow I get an error that says Cake can't find the class Address.  It's actually loading the address.php file, but for some reason it can't access the class. What am I doing wrong?

```
  $address_params = array("name" => "Sawyer Bateman",
            "street1" => "388 Townasend St",
            //"street2" => "Apt 20",
            "city" => "San Francisco",
            "state" => "CA",
            "zip" => "94107",
            "country" => "US");

        $address = Address::create($address_params);
        $debug($address);
```

EasyPost.Easypost

```
 App::uses('EasyPostAppModel', 'EasyPost.Model');
 class EasyPost extends EasyPostAppModel {

 public $name = 'EasyPost';
 public $useTable = false;
 public static $apiKey;
 public static $apiBase = 'https://api.easypost.com/v2';
 public static $apiVersion = "2";

const VERSION = '2.0.7';

public static function getApiKey() {
    return self::$apiKey;
}

public static function setApiKey($apiKey) {
    self::$apiKey = $apiKey;
}

public static function getApiBase() {
    return self::$apiBase;
}

public static function setApiBase($apiBase) {
    self::$apiBase = $apiBase;
}

public static function getApiVersion() {
    return self::$apiVersion;
}

public static function setApiVersion($apiVersion) {
    self::$apiVersion = $apiVersion;
}

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        EasyPost::setApiKey(XXX);

        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/Util.php');
        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/Error.php');

        // Guts
        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/Object.php');
        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/Resource.php');
        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/Requestor.php');

        // API Resources

        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/Address.php');
        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/ScanForm.php');
        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/CustomsItem.php');
        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/CustomsInfo.php');
        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/Parcel.php');
        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/Rate.php');
        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/PostageLabel.php');
        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/Shipment.php');
        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/Refund.php');
        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/Batch.php');
        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/Tracker.php');
        require(App::pluginPath('EasyPost') . 'Lib/EasyPost/Event.php');



}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem has nothing to do with CakePHP, you're just missing the `EasyPost` [namespace](http://php.net/namespaces) where the `Address` class lives (assuming the code you are showing here is actually executed *after* the class file has been included):

```
$address = \EasyPost\Address::create($address_params);
```